# Gpiocontrol demo C SDK not seen on Amazon EC2 Sandbox

Tags: amazon-ec2, esp8266, kaa

I am new to Kaa, I am trying to use the gpiocontrol sample on my esp8266, as per my understanding on the Amazon EC2 Sandbox, I did not find the CSDK download option for the gpiocontrol as seen on the youtube video tutorial. I understand that CSDK needs to be generated on Kaa Sandbox via the Admin UI, but the GPIOControl for the ESP8266 is not visible.

Is there a way add my own application on the sandbox, what is the process to do that?

Please revert

Answer (score 0):

You should normally not add your application(s) to the Kaa Sandbox. This process is quite complex and requires many steps to be done.

Regarding your issue with ESP8266, this sample application is disabled in the Kaa Sandbox 0.10.0 due to unresolved at the time of the Kaa 0.10.0 release issues.

You can await for the Kaa 0.10.1 Sandbox release which is planned soon. Or, you can use the ESP8266 code from [GitHub](https://github.com/kaaproject/sample-apps/tree/master/gpiocontrol/source/c) together with the SDK from your Kaa Sandbox instance to build the new and fixed sample application.